# How to use Emacs to write comments with proper indentation, line-length, and wrapping?

Tags: emacs, comments, word-wrap, line-breaks

I'm tired of writing comments that look like this

```
{
    # bla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla
    # bla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla blabla bla bla
    # blaaa bla
}
```

I have to manually wrap the lines and take care of the # as well. How do emacs pros make the editor work for them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `auto-fill-mode` together with `comment-auto-fill-only-comments` (the latter is from `newcomment.el`).

Comment: That is wonderful. I added the following to my .emacs. Works perfectly. Thank you!

(require 'newcomment)
(setq comment-auto-fill-only-comments 1)
(setq-default auto-fill-function 'do-auto-fill)

Answer (score 23):

Selecting the comment and hitting M-q will usually reformat it.

M-q is generally mapped to `fill-paragraph`, `c-fill-paragraph`, or some other mode-specific variant.

Comment: +1 Assuming you are in the right mode, anyway. Also beware that many modes have tunable formatting parameters.

Comment: Exactly what I would have written. +1.

Comment: The column for word-wrapping the lines of a paragraph can be set with (setq-default fill-column 80).